# Repeat the loop at a specified time

Tags: java, while-loop, timer

I need a loop to repeat at a specific time

For example 10 seconds :

```
while (Repeat every ten seconds)
        {
           // Code body
        }
```

Comment: This isn't an algorithm question. Please remove the algorithm tag.

Comment: `while (something) { do it once; wait 10 secs; }`  or depending on what you precisely want, wait 10 secs less the time taken to do it once.

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep(10000)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pause the code execution into a java loop you can use `Thread.sleep(Integer)` method, that will stop the execution of the thread for the specified amount of milliseconds. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) there is an official example with a `for` loop. In your case you could do something like this:

```
while (true) {
  /* your code here */
  Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

The body of the `while` loop will be executed once every 10 seconds.

Comment: `while(1)` seems to be C and not Java. You meant `while(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you cannot do that. You can make a loop that does something like

```java
while(true){
   ... do your sheet ...
   Thread.sleep(10_000);
   }
```

But it will not be precisely every 10 seconds.

This solution will likely be okay for you, though.

What you have to consider is the followings:

- What happens if the `do your sheet` runs for 9 sec? Should you wait 10 sec more or only the remaining 1 sec?
- What happens if the action takes more than 10sec? Should you repeat it immediately or 10 sec after the start of the action? Should the program start the action again in a different thread? How many threads should the program start?

Also, there is no guarantee that the `Thread.sleep(10_000)` will suspend the execution of the current thread for exactly 10 seconds. It may get back from sleep sooner, because of an interrupt/signal. Also the thread may get back from sleep later because there is no free resource to execute the thread right after the 10 sec have passed.

For a simple exercise the `while` loop and the `sleep()` are okay. If you later will need something more professional then you can read the documentation, and consider the use of Quartz.